# Stuck in color dungeon, one little key short

Tags: zelda-links-awakening-2019

Did I just do something stupid? I used my last small key and opened the wrong door. Now I can't get past the the last locked door, to retrieve the boss key. How do I fix this?

[image: map]

Comment: Okeeej, found it. Thanks, it just took one more try. Now I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

Every Zelda dungeon is designed to be completed. Just because you have opened all the chests doesnt mean there isnt a key somewhere in the dungeon. Sometimes keys will spawn after killing all the enemies in the room, for those there wont be a chest. I believe as long as you have the compass, [if you enter a room where a key is you will hear the special tone that indicates there is one](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Compass).